# ¿Cómo ingresar el resultado de un cursor a un arreglo en Sql Server?

Tags: sql-server

Necesito que el resultado de un cursor se pueda almacenar en un arreglo, algo como lo siguiente:

```
DECLARE RegistrosCursor CURSOR FOR  
select rbd
from TablaTemporal
order by rbd;

set @i=0;

OPEN RegistrosCursor;  
FETCH NEXT FROM RegistrosCursor  
INTO @rbd;  

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
BEGIN  
        set @i = @i + 1;
        datos[i]=@rbd;

   FETCH NEXT FROM RegistrosCursor  
   INTO @cod_ense, @rbd;  
END;  

CLOSE RegistrosCursor;  
DEALLOCATE RegistrosCursor;  
GO
```

No sé si se puede declarar una variable arreglo en sql server y en caso de que no se pueda, cómo se puede implementar lo que estoy planteando.

En base al aporte que me ha hecho **Patricio Moracho**, hice la siguiente modificación al código considerando un tipo de variable Tabla:

**CONSULTA PRINCIPAL**

```
DECLARE @par TABLE(id int, cod_ense int, cod_grado int);
INSERT INTO @par SELECT id,cod_ense, cod_grado FROM ENSEÑANZA_GRADO;
SELECT * FROM TOT_MAT_NIVEL_15_16_17 t
WHERE t.COD_ENSEÑANZA in(select cod_ense from @par where id=1) AND 
  t.GRADO in(select cod_grado from @par where id=1)
```

Pero la consulta **no retorna datos**.

Verifico que la variable Tabla @par tenga datos:

```
DECLARE @par TABLE(id int, cod_ense int, cod_grado int);
INSERT INTO @par SELECT id,cod_ense, cod_grado FROM ENSEÑANZA_GRADO;
select id,cod_ense, cod_grado from @par;
```

La cual me devuelve:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por lo tanto la variable Tabla sí contiene los datos. No entiendo por qué no retorna datos.

Hice un pequeño cambio en la CONSULTA PRINCIPAL, dejando sólo el filtro (where) del cod_ense:

```
DECLARE @par TABLE(id int, cod_ense int, cod_grado int);
INSERT INTO @par SELECT id,cod_ense, cod_grado FROM ENSEÑANZA_GRADO;
SELECT * FROM TOT_MAT_NIVEL_15_16_17 t
WHERE t.COD_ENSEÑANZA in(select cod_ense from @par where id=1)
```

Con lo cual sí me retornan registros. Entonces entendería que no se puede invocar más de una vez la variable Tabla en la consulta; por favor, me puede confirmar si esto es así?

En el mismo contexto de la pregunta, ¿se podría almacenar en una variable el resultado de una consulta a un campo de una variable tipo Tabla, algo como lo siguiente?

```
DECLARE @par TABLE(id int, cod_ense int, cod_grado int);
DECLARE @a int;
INSERT INTO @par SELECT id,cod_ense, cod_grado FROM ENSEÑANZA_GRADO;
set @a = select cod_ense from @par where id=1;
```

A mi me arroja error. Cómo se podría implementar esta asignación?

Comment: Antes que nada, en estos caso, deberías hacer otra pregunta,ya que de hecho lo es, de ese modo también tendrías más chances de obtener una respuesta. Una variable tipo tabla es una tabla más y se puede usar las veces que lo necesites. Así como estás haciendo la consulta deberías verificar que en `TOT_MAT_NIVEL_15_16_17` tengas registros para `cod_ense=10` y `cod_grado=1`, también te diría que no uses subconsultas sino directamente un `JOIN` así: `SELECT * FROM TOT_MAT_NIVEL_15_16_17 t INNER JOIN @par p ON p.cod_ense = t.cod_ense AND p.cod_grado = t.cod_grado WHERE p.id = 1`

Answer (score 2):

No existe ningún tipo de dato "Array" en SQL Server (al menos a la fecha), la única forma de manejar algo similar a estos es con una simple y clásica tabla. Sin embargo si el uso que le quieres dar apunto a algo temporal, puede serte útil: (1) las variables tipo tabla o (2) las tablas temporales. Conceptualmente son tablas como cualquier otra, pero se orientan a un uso en el corto plazo.

Veamos un ejemplo de variables tipo `TABLA`:

```
-- Declaro la variable tipo tabla
DECLARE @datos TABLE(
  id INT IDENTITY, -- El ID no es obligatorio pero si útil
  Valor INT
)

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
BEGIN  
        set @i = @i + 1;
        -- inserto una fila con el valor de la variable @rbd 
        INSERT INTO @datos(Valor) VALUES(@rbd)

   FETCH NEXT FROM RegistrosCursor  
   INTO @cod_ense, @rbd;  
END;  

-- El funcionamiento es el habitual para cualquier tabla
SELECT * FROM @datos
```

Estas variables solo existen mientras se usan en la sesión como cualquier otra variable, no es necesario "dropearlas" explícitamente.

Por otro lado, las tablas temporales, pueden ser globales (son visibles por múltiples sesiones y existen mientras cualquier sesión que la hubiera usado permanezca activa) o de sesión (solo viven en la sesión en que se hubieran creado). La diferencia con las variables tipo `TABLA` en cuanto al uso, son mínimas, solo cambia la declaración, que debe hacerse como cualquier tabla, es decir con un `CREATE` y el nombre de la tabla tendrá un `#` o `##` de acuerdo a si son de sesión o globales, ejemplo:

```
CREATE TABLE #Datos ( ...
```

o

```
CREATE TABLE ##Datos ( ...
```

Hay muchas particularidades mas de cada tipo de tabla, pero me parece que estaríamos fuera del alcance de tu pregunta.

Comment: Muchas gracias Patricio por tu respuesta. En función de lo que me dijiste hice una variación en el código, la cual he agregado en el cuerpo principal de mi pregunta inicial, de modo que se pueda visualizar mejor el código. Ahí te formulo una pregunta, pues la implementación no me arroja el resultado completo.